Claims Identity Not Authenticated
I'm using Cookies Authentication, but after User Validate there is validated true. enter image description here
But after Login, there is shown User Identity not Authenticatedenter image description here
I want to fetch Claims Values in Controller, but when I Call User in Controller there is null value.
Here I mention Code snippet in .net Core:
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl = null)
  {
      ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {

          User user = validateUser(model.Email, model.Password);
          if (user != null)
          {
              // Valid user credentials


              // Sanitize user data before storing in cookie
              model.Email = Uri.EscapeDataString(model.Email);

              // Create authentication claims
              var claims = new List<Claim>
              {
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UsEmail),
              // Add additional claims as needed
              };


              var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

              var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
              {
                  AllowRefresh = true,
                  IsPersistent = model.RememberMe, // Set persistence based on checkbox
              };

              try
              {
                  await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                      claimsPrincipal,
                      authProperties);

                  var isAuth = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  // Log error and handle accordingly
              }

              if (user.Role == "User")
              {
                  return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/Home"));
              }
              else
              {
                  return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/Admin"));
              }
          }
          else
          {
              ViewData["message"] = "Invalid login credentials.";
              return View();
          }
      }

      // If data is invalid (including potential SQL comment characters)
      ViewData["message"] = "Invalid Provided Data.";
      return View();
  }


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "YourAuthCookieName";

        options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";

        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); // Set cookie expiration for "Remember Me"
        options.SlidingExpiration = true; // Refresh cookie on activity
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // Mitigate XSS risks
      //options.Cookie.Secure = true;   // Enforce HTTPS-only cookies (if applicable)
    });


// Add IHttpContextAccessor
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSession();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();



Please post the code as text, not a screenshot

@toyotaSupra please review my code, I had edited my post

After testing your code, the authentication is working as expected.In response to your problem, here are the reasons:

After User Validate there is validated true.

It is because you're using CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme for authentication and adding claims to the ClaimsIdentity object, by default, the ClaimsIdentity is marked as authenticated. So, when you set it as part of the ClaimsPrincipal object, the ClaimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated property is automatically set to true.

After Login, there is shown User Identity not Authenticated

In the first POST request of the login, the authentication cookies have not been saved yet, therefore there is shown User Identity not Authenticated.


And after being redirected to a protected page, the browser saves cookies, then the HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property will be set to true. You can verify it again in the protected page as shown below.



when I Call User in Controller there is null value

The reason is the same: during the first POST request of the login, the client browser has not yet saved the authentication cookies, hence, the HttpContext user cannot be retrieved. It's only upon redirection to the protected page that the browser was triggered to save cookies, making it possible to retrieve the user.
